# Why am I getting null pointer exception when I add an item to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, junit, mockito

I have my Prescription class as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Prescription {

    private final ArrayList<Product> prescriptionItems = new     ArrayList<Product>();
    private long prescriptionId;

    public List<Product> getPrescriptionItems() {
        return prescriptionItems;
    }

    public void addPrescriptionItem(final Product product) {
        this.prescriptionItems.add(product);
    }
}
```

I have my Product class as follows

```
public class Product {

    public Product(final long productCode, final double productCost) {
        this.productCode = productCode;
        this.productCost = productCost;
    }


    private final long productCode;
    private final double productCost;

    public long getProductCode() {
        return productCode;
    }

      public double getProductCost() {
        return productCost;
       }
}
```

I have my test setup as follows:
   I have my setUp method as follows:

```
        @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception 
        {
            medAvailControllerImpl = new MedAvailControllerImpl(medAvailDAO, dispenser, paymentHandlerFactory);
        prescriptionProduct = new Product(789, 44.0);
        customer = new Customer(45678, "Amofa Baffoe", "Claregalway", "kbaffoe@hotmail.com", "paypal", paypalStrategy);
        when(medAvailDAO.getCustomerForId(45678)).thenReturn(customer);
    }
```

I have my JUnit/Mockito test as follows:

```
    @Test
    public void testOneItemOnPrescriptionSuccess() throws Exception {
        //prescriptionProduct = new Product(789, 44.0);
        prescriptionItems.add(prescriptionProduct);
            when(prescription.getPrescriptionItems()).thenReturn(prescriptionItems);

    }
```

Am getting `NullPointerException` at where `prescriptionItems` is added to `prescriptionProduct`. Any help?

Comment: Tnx for quick response. Is this test working for you?

public void testOneItemOnPrescriptionSuccess() throws Exception {
  prescriptionProduct = new Product(789, 44.0);
  prescriptionItems.add(prescriptionProduct);
  when(prescription.getPrescriptionItems()).thenReturn(prescriptionItems);

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your code in my computer and it worked, added a product and returned it using `List<Product> getPrescriptionItems()` flawlessly.

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.List;

class Product {
    public Product(final long productCode, final double productCost) {
        this.productCode = productCode;
        this.productCost = productCost;
    }


    private final long productCode;
    private final double productCost;

    public long getProductCode() {
        return productCode;
    }

      public double getProductCost() {
        return productCost;
      }
}  
public class Prescription {

    private final ArrayList<Product> prescriptionItems = new ArrayList<Product>();
    private long prescriptionId;

    public List<Product> getPrescriptionItems() {
        return prescriptionItems;
    }

    public void addPrescriptionItem(final Product product) {
        this.prescriptionItems.add(product);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // instantiate Prescription
        Prescription pres = new Prescription();

        // add a product to ArrayList using addPrescriptionItem()
        pres.addPrescriptionItem(new Product(50, 15.0));

        // get the product details from the ArrayList
        Product product = pres.getPrescriptionItems().get(0);

        System.out.println(product.getProductCode()+ " " + product.getProductCost()); // will print "name in sup Class"
    }
}
```

Here is the output:
[image: the output]

Comment: This should be posted as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: I tried to post it as a comment but apparently I can't, I still have 11 reputations.

Comment: Oh...no worries..keep contributing...I wish you success!.

Comment: Am getting Null Pointer Exception when I do this:

prescriptionProduct = new Product(789, 44.0);
prescriptionItems.add(prescriptionProduct);

Comment: @AmofaBaffoe I just added the product like you did,  
// instantiate Prescription
Prescription pres = new Prescription();

pres.addPrescriptionItem(new Product(50, 15.0));  like showen in the code I sent above and it worked. No null exception were thrown.

Comment: You need to carefully go through the code as a whole and look for what is missing. did you instantiated prescriptionItems or product correctly

Comment: Maybe you referenced  prescriptionItems at a point where it still null and not pointing to an object

Comment: Here are my declared variables in the code

private final MedAvailDAO medAvailDAO = mock(MedAvailDAO.class);
 private final Dispenser dispenser = mock(Dispenser.class);
 private final PaymentHandlerFactory paymentHandlerFactory = mock(PaymentHandlerFactory.class);
 private PayPalHandler payPalHandler = mock(PayPalHandler.class);
 private MedAvailControllerImpl medAvailControllerImpl;
 private Customer customer;
 private Prescription prescription;
 private ArrayList <Product> prescriptionItems;
 private Product prescriptionProduct;
 private int productInStock;

Comment: Here is my test setUp:

@BeforeEach
 void setUp() throws Exception {
  medAvailControllerImpl = new MedAvailControllerImpl(medAvailDAO, dispenser, paymentHandlerFactory);
  customer = new Customer(45678, "Amofa Baffoe", "Claregalway", "kbaffoe@hotmail.com", "paypal", paypalStrategy);
  when(medAvailDAO.getCustomerForId(45678)).thenReturn(customer);
   }

Comment: Here is my test with the null pointer exception:

@Test
 public void testOneItemOnPrescriptionSuccess() throws Exception {
  productInStock = 980;
  prescriptionProduct = new Product(789, 44.0);
  prescriptionItems.add(prescriptionProduct);
  when(prescription.getPrescriptionItems()).thenReturn(prescriptionItems);
  verify(medAvailDAO, new Times(0)).getCustomerForId(45678);
  verify(medAvailDAO, new Times(0)).getPrescriptionForId(anyInt());  
when(medAvailDAO.checkProductInStock(productInStock)).thenReturn(true) 
 }

Answer (score 0):

try initializing prescriptionItems ArrayList :

```
private ArrayList <Product> prescriptionItems;
```

to

```
private ArrayList <Product> prescriptionItems = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

when you declared it in the test code.

By the way why you adding a new ArrayList for products if you want to test adding product through **addPrescriptionItem** method inside **prescription** class which adds the product to the ArrayList already defined inside Prescription class.